# Pushing data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook `book1.xlsm` and another one as `book2.xls`. I want to push values from `book1` to `book2` via a macro running in `book1`.

Is there a way in which even if the workbook `book2` is closed the value is pushed to it?

The main reason for asking this is that it will skip the problem of saving `book2` again and again after a new value is inserted.

Comment: You could use formulas in Book 2, that way when you re-open it, those formulas evaluate based on the reference to Book1. But I suspect this is not what you want.  There is no way to "push values" to a workbook file that is not open. You will get an error if you try.

Comment: You could use the macro to silently open Book2, insert the value, and then save & close Book2.  All this can be done pretty simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is ***No***

The longer answer is ...

... whatever technology you use to get updates into a file (patching on the O/S byte level, using application programmes, etc. ...), it always means to open / update / save / close the file (*allthough on the lowest level a "file" may be a sector on the hard drive*). Some techno's are faster than others, though ...

So don't waste time ... if you can't do by creating formulas in Book2 that retrieve data from Book1- as suggested in the comments to your question - write code in Book1 to open / update / close Book1

By carefull and intelligent use of events like `Workbook_Open()` and `Workbook_BeforeClose(...)` you can care for synchronisation and hence minimizing the number of openings / savings  /closings of Book2